# onCreateView does not fired in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

At first the problem was getView() always returns null in my fragment . so as others offer I used a View in onCreateView  to get view like this :

```
     private  View vv ;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    vv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exam_page2, container, false); ;
    return  vv ;

}
```

so I could use vv instead of getView() . But now I see that onCreateView does not get called at all ! 
in my activity I do this :

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    TwoLineOptionsFragment twoLineOptionsFragment = new TwoLineOptionsFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_answerContainer, twoLineOptionsFragment).commit();

            twoLineOptionsFragment.updateOptions(question.AnswerOptions) ;// my public function doing stuff ...
```

so where is the problem ?

EDIT : here is my function if matters :

```
    public  boolean updateOptions(ArrayList<Exam.Question.Answer> answers)
    {
    try
    {


        QuestionOptionView optionView = (QuestionOptionView)(vv.findViewById(R.id.option1)) ;
        //QuestionOptionView optionView = (QuestionOptionView)(getView().findViewById(R.id.option1)) ;
        optionView.setText(answers.get(0).AnswerText);
    return reue ;
    }
    // ... 
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you're creating `transaction` object in the above code ?

Comment: also post code from `updateOptions()` method

Comment: Try putting a log inside in `onCreateView` and tell us if it does not show up. IMO it should be called unless the Fragment turns into a No view Fragment which is possible.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh edited my question

Comment: see the @Darish answer thats the actual problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onCreateView() of Fragment will get called always. The problem in your case is you are trying to access the view object before onCreateView() get called. The following get executed too early.

```
 twoLineOptionsFragment.updateOptions(question.AnswerOptions) ;
```

Don't call `Fragment` methods directly from the activity, because you may not sure that `Fragment` is ready or not. You should move your logic into `Fragment` class itself and provide a callback to `Activity` so that you can pass results back to the Activity.

In your case, you can pass `answers.get(0).AnswerText` value as an argument to Fragment and display it on the TextView. cheers :)

```
TwoLineOptionsFragment f = new TwoLineOptionsFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("arg", answers.get(0).AnswerText);
f.setArguments(args);
```

Comment: but I need to do it from Activity . is there any way to check if fragment is ready ?

Comment: in this case problem is solved , but now what should I do if  I need an update in fragment not just pass values at first time ?

Comment: add a callback to the parent Activity and get the value dynamically

Comment: callback is useful if I want to get changes from fragment in Activity .  I mean Consider a situation something has changed in Activity not in fragment , and I want to change something in fragment from Activity ,

Comment: if the fragment is alive and ready, you can pass it directly from activity. define a boolean in your fragment class and set it true on onCreateView() and set it  false on OnDestroy(). Then you can check that value to determine whether the fragment is ready or not.